# Apache Cassandra Unable to load a csql file

Tags: csv, cassandra

I'm just starting out with Apache Cassandra. I have some csql files that define my data. I have got Cassandra installed on my machine and I did start it as per Apache Cassandra Wiki. Nothing suspicious!

I'm using the CLI to create the namespaces and the tables for which I have some cql files in a specific directory like:

```
create_tables.cql
load_tables.cql
```

I was able to successfully do the create_tables.cql, but when I tried to urn the load_tables.cql, I always end up seeing:

```
/Users/myUser/data/load-test-data.cql:7:Can't open 'test_data.csv' for reading: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test_data.csv'
```

The load_tables.cql refers to another csv file that contains the test data that I want to populate my database with!

```
COPY test_table (id, name) FROM 'test_data.csv';
```

I tried doing al sort of permissions to the data folder where the cql files are, but still I keep getting this message. Any hints as to what I could do to get this solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I got this one sorted! It has got to do with the absolute and relative paths. I ended up using an absolute path to where my CSV is located! This solved the issue!

Comment: Is it strict necessary to be an absolute path? I'm asking that because I'm using it under a docker container and the path may change. Thanks in advance!